# Zip a file as a subcommand

Tags: zip, binary

I am trying to combine these two commands into one:

`zip -r my-app.zip ./*; aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction --zip-file fileb://my-app.zip`

I have tried:

`<()`

`aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction --zip-file fileb://<(zip -r my-app.zip ./*)`

and `$()`

`aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction --zip-file fileb://$(zip -r my-app.zip ./*)`

But neither seem to work. I don't think the zip operation is being run as a subcommand, but I might be wrong, I can't see anything happening in the terminal though.

Any ideas on the correct syntax for this? Thanks

Comment: What if you use `-` as the zip filename when invoking `zip`? Try the process substitution `<(zip ...)` syntax with `-` as the filename, this should write the `zip` output to the standard output. If you're not writing the result to the standard output, `<()` `$()` will not have the result of compressing the files. And if you want to provide a filename to `aws`, then you probably need `<()`, not `$()` (the first is replaced with the name of a file which will have the output of the `zip` command, the second is replaced with the output of the `zip` command).

Comment: Amazing! using `-` works great, thanks a lot! Thanks also for the detailed explanation!

Comment: I don't understand the question. In what way does your first code snippet not do what you want?

Comment: I believe the first command (two separate commands) does what @timhc22 wants, but the goal is to do both "at once".